# Function call with const std::string& and const std::vector<std::string>&

Tags: c++

I have functions with signatures:

```cpp
    void add_word_rule(const std::string& word);
    void add_multiple_word_rules(const std::vector<std::string>& words);
```

The problem is this. If the user calls the function

```cpp
    add_word_rule({"word_1","word_2"});
```

It will compile . How can I ensure that such a call does not compile?
How can I disable this constructor `basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last)` ?

Comment: If your intention is to pass a vector, thus calling `add_multiple_word_rules`, just prepend `std::vector` to  `{`.

Comment: please read about [mcve]. `std::vector` and `word_rule` and the other function seem to be irrelevant, but its factors that make it harder for others to get your code to compile

Comment: @molbdnilo [really?](https://godbolt.org/z/EYn4M7svn)

Comment: [Same result with edited q](https://godbolt.org/z/nqx3d3v3v)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a deleted overload for `std::initializer_list<const char*>`:

```cpp
#include <string>

void add_word_rule(const std::string& word)
{}

void add_word_rule(std::initializer_list<const char*>) = delete;

int main(){
   add_word_rule({"word1", "word2"}); // compiler error
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7rG9bdW7b

Answer (score 8):

You cannot prevent a user from making mistakes. You should expect a user to be familiar with `std::string` and its implicit conversions. However, if you want to do something about it, you can disable implicit conversions by turning the function into a function template that only accepts `std::string`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,std::string>> add_word_rule(const T& word){}

int main() {
     //add_word_rule({"word_1","word_2"});  // error 
     //add_word_rule("word_1");             // error
     add_word_rule(std::string{"word_1"});  // ok
}
```

If someone wants to break it, they can still do so, by explicitly specifying `T`, eg `add_word_rule<std::string>({"word_1","word_2"});`. And no changes in your signature can prevent a user from writing

```
std::string s{"word_1","word_2"}; // WRONG !!
add_word_rule(s);
```

which is basically the same mistake. My advice is: Don't try to be prepared for a user that ignores documentation. Eventually you can't and they will find a way to break things.

---

PS: I suppose you mention `void add_multiple_word_rules(const std::vector<std::string>& words);` because thats what might lead a user to mistakenly call `add_word_rule({"word_1","word_2"});` when they expect to pass a `std::vector<std::string>`. Note that if you had used overloads, this is a non-issue, because with

```
void add_word_rule(const std::string& word) {}
void add_word_rule(const std::vector<std::string>& words){ }
```

The call `add_word_rule({"word_1","word_2"})` is ambiguous and the caller cannot make that mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You could disable using temporary strings altogether by deleting overload accepting rvalue references:

```
void add_word_rule(std::string&& word) = delete;
```

Note that this will also disallow `add_word_rule("word1");`. You could bring it back by adding yet another overload to accept `const char*`:

```
void add_word_rule(const char* word)
{
    std::string s {word};
    add_word_rule(s);
}
```